# C# Not enough storage is available to process this command on Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

This is my code

```
static void Main()
        {
            /*
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new OpenTableImporter() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);*/
            XMLReader x = new XMLReader(new LogCustome());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I got:

`Not enough storage is available to process this command.` on `Console.ReadLine()`

could you help please?

#### Update 1

the class `LogCustome` is almost empty as you see:

```
class LogCustome
    {
        public void logStartService() { }

        public void logStopService() { }
    }
```

#### Update2

Even when the code is as simple as this:

```
static void Main()
        {
            /*
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new OpenTableImporter() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);*/
            //XMLReader x = new XMLReader(new LogCustome());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I still have the exception

Comment: What does the constructor for `LogCustome` do? there isn't really enough information here to help. At least a stack trace is needed

Comment: @Sayse I have update my question adding the `LogCustome` class, very simple class

Comment: And what's the code for the constructor of `XMLReader`? Not to be confused with `System.Xml.XmlReader`, I suppose?

Comment: @JeroenMostert that is my custom class, not the .net class, anyway, I updated the question and stated that when my `main` is just `Console.ReadLine()`, I still have that exception

Comment: Is the problem in Console.RadLine()? fi you comment out the XMLReader line, does it happen?

Comment: @ShayD as you see in my `Update2`, I have already tried your suggestion and still have the problem

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/995906/67392 this is likely to be a memory issue.

Comment: Guys, I am sorry if the question is not good, but I would appreciate if you tell me why you are down voting. Plus, Now, I guess, the question is clear.

Comment: The question isn't clear at all, is the exception actually in your program or is your OS reporting it? if its in your program then you would have a stack trace, if it isn't then you need to look at your memory usage of your computer

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: now it's getting interesting. Does it persist if you remove any `app.config` you have? Does it appear or disappear if you run it in the debugger? Do you get an exception with a stack trace and if so, what does it say?

Comment: @Sayse I don't know where the problem could have happened, that is why I am asking here. If I had knew that the problem in my OS, I would have stated that. Anyway, I am ready to provide you with any information, I don't know what to check

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't get a `stack trace` exception. and I don't know what do you mean buy `run it in the debugger`

Comment: I will try to restart my computer and come back to you after 4-5 minutes

Comment: MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms837395.aspx
Do one of the following, then retry the command: (1) reduce the number of running programs; (2) remove unwanted files from the disk the paging file is on and restart the system; (3) check the paging file disk for an I/O error; or (4) install additional memory in your system.

Comment: @BramVanStrydonck I am working on computer 16GB ram, and after restart the computer, just 2GB are being used, I have more than 200GB free in my driver. help please

Comment: You are almost certainly not having any memory trouble -- the error code is a red herring. The trouble is, finding out the root cause is difficult and Stack Overflow isn't really intended for such bug hunts. For example, you may have a piece of software injecting a rogue DLL that hooks system functions, causing `Console.ReadLine()` to fail with a spurious error. Diagnosing this is not simple. A reinstall of Windows will almost certainly work... but may be a bit too drastic.

Answer (score 2):

Likely on the project properties (since you created it as a service), Output Type is a Windows Application, change that to Console Application and it'll work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Is the amount of data you're trying to read over 254 characters?

Refer to:
[How to read very long input from console in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750853/how-to-read-very-long-input-from-console-in-c)
[Console.ReadLine() max length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557889/console-readline-max-length)

Comment: I couldn't run the app at the first place,